# BrowserRouter - Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, react-typescript

I have upgraded the react version to 18 and getting some type error from BrowserRouter component, Tried different approach and not able to recognize what's the problem is.

Below is the error when I am debugging the code,

```
     Overload 1 of 2, '(props: BrowserRouterProps | Readonly<BrowserRouterProps>): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<BrowserRouterProps>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: BrowserRouterProps, context: any): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<BrowserRouterProps>'.
```

[image: error message]

A helping hand would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing a similar issue with `@types/react-router-dom@5.3.0`. Running

`npm install @types/react-router-dom@5.3.3`

fixed it.

The BrowserRouterProps interface in version 5.3.3 looks like so:

```
export interface BrowserRouterProps {
    basename?: string | undefined;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    getUserConfirmation?: ((message: string, callback: (ok: boolean) => void) => void) | undefined;
    forceRefresh?: boolean | undefined;
    keyLength?: number | undefined;
}
```

and it seems version 5.3.0 does not have the optional children field.